# Query on object array in mongoDB with spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, nosql

I have mongoDB colletion as follows

```
{
  "_id": "ba4d5a0e-1759-4e88-bd57-5e7781d46da7",
  "name": "Doc 3 updated",
  "documentClass": "033a1f67-b382-43f5-b1e4-7ade26f1522c",
  "documentClassName": "Sample Document",
  "meta": [
    {
      "index_field_id": "9e744f36-1c63-45e8-8180-3ceef894b724",
      "value": "a"
    },
    {
      "index_field_id": "08afba06-9a7e-4df8-a946-a8cccbefda8b",
      "value": "asafsf"
    }
  ],
  "version": 2,
  "archived": false,
  "checkedOut": false,
  "checkedOutBy": "svpadm",
  "created": {
    "$date": "2023-12-24T11:12:39.580Z"
  },
  "modified": {
    "$date": "2024-01-09T19:48:29.785Z"
  },
  "owner": "79866869-398a-4920-975b-032decc12461",
  "ownerClear": "svpadm",
  "tenant": "ECMDEV01-T",
  "updatedBy": "79866869-398a-4920-975b-032decc12461",
  "updatedByClear": "svpadm",
  "_class": "de.metasonic.cloud.models.database.Document"
}
```

Then I want to search this document by a `phrase` and then want to check whether any of `indexFieldsId` in following `List<String> indexFieldIds` is there in `meta` object array, So I found a query for that

```
@Query("{$and: ["
            + " {$or: ["
            + "  {'name': {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}}, "
            + "  {'documentClass': {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}}, "
            + "  {'documentClassName': {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}}, "
            + "  {'workbookId': {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}}, "
            + "  {'owner': {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}}, "
            + "  {'ownerClear': {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}}, "
            + "  {'tenant': {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}}, "
            + "  {'updatedBy': {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}}, "
            + "  {'updatedByClear': {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}}, "
            + "  {'linkedDocuments': {$elemMatch: {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}}}, "
            + "  {'providerState': {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}}, "
            + "  {'providerMetaData': {$elemMatch: {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}}}"
            + " ]},"
            + " {'meta': {$elemMatch: {'index_field_id': {$in: ?1}}}}"
            + "]}"
    )
    Page<Document> searchByPhraseAndIndexFieldIds(String searchPhrase, List<String> indexFieldIds, Pageable pageable);
```

this is the meta object,

```
public class DocumentMetaDTO {
    String index_field_id;
    Object value;
    ArrayList<DocumentMetaDTO> categoryValues;
}
```

but it gives me an exception

```
Exception : org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query failed with error code 2 with name 'BadValue' and error message '$elemMatch needs an Object' on server localhost:27018; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 with name 'BadValue' and error message '$elemMatch needs an Object' on server localhost:27018
```

can someone help me on this

Comment: Where are `linkedDocuments` and `providerMetaData` properties in your document? You are doing an `$elemMatch` on them. Also, where is `workbookId` property? Are these added in an aggegation stage or just errors?

Comment: Those are List of string values, only thing that I'm worry is searching index field id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have a single query condition when using `$elemMatch`. The [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#syntax) state:

> If you specify only a single  condition in the `$elemMatch` expression, and are not using the `$not` or `$ne` operators inside of `$elemMatch`, `$elemMatch` can be omitted.

I don't use Spring and this error doesn't happen in Node but that that would mean you can change to:

```js
{'linkedDocuments': {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}},
```

and

```js
 {'providerMetaData': {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}}"
```

instead of using `$elemMatch`. This is likely due to the fact you haven't provided any keys to the `$elemMatch` e.g

```js
{'linkedDocuments': { $elemMatch: { key1: { $regex: ?0, $options: 'i' }, key2: ?1 } }},
```

**Edit**:

For the `meta` query a single query condition mean you should try:

```js
{'meta.index_field_id': {$in: ?1}}
```

Comment: i have issue with " {'meta': {$elemMatch: {'index_field_id': {$in: ?1}}}}" this. because rest of the query is working

Comment: @Viranga what is the error? The value passed to `$in` needs to be an array.

Comment: Hi, @JQueeny, I want to query database with searchPhrase and also with List of Ids. But i want to check that ids only with the index_field_ids inside the meta object array.. Im getting `Query failed with error code 2 with name 'BadValue' and error message '$elemMatch needs an Object' on server localhost:27018` exception

Comment: Is `meta` an array of objects or just an object? @Viranga

Comment: it is an array of objects

Comment: @Viranga I have edited the answer. Hopefully that helps.